# Git commit date

Tags: git

Other than parsing git log for the date string, is there a Git native way to report the date of a certain commit?

Comment: Good stuff : https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats

Answer (score 411, accepted):

The
show
command may be what you want. Try

```
git show --no-patch --format=%ci <commit>
```

Other formats for the date string are available as well. Check the [manual page](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-show) for
details.

Comment: To get the commit without its diff, use `log -1` instead of `show`.

Comment: Or add the '-s' to the command:
`git show -s --format="%ci" <commit>`

Comment: For future users: you can view the *author date* with `%ai`.

Comment: @Mehrdad  I'm looking to accomplish this with all the files in a `repo  git ls-tree -r --name-only HEAD` sent through a loop doesn't give me a specific date-time.

Comment: to get just unix timestamp: use git show -s --format=%ct <commit>

Comment: If you want another date format, you can use `git show -s --format=%cd --date=short <commit>` (will give e.g. 2016-11-02) or `git show -s --format=%cd --date=short <commit>` or `git show -s --format=%cd --date=format:%Y <commit>` (this example will print only the year) For details see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19742762/935676).

Comment: It is _significantly_ faster to use `log -1` rather than `show -s` for large merge commits so I definitely recommend using `log -1` if you are trying to find stale branches. This sped it up from hours to minutes in the case of the monorepo I'm working with right now.

Comment: `git show -s --format=%ci` is what I wanted (for most recent commit)

Comment: The `git show -s` variant will sometimes output some extra information beyond the date (`Tagger: someone`  and some log message), I don’t know if this is a bug in GIT or some intended behaviour, but `git log -1` does not do this.

Answer (score 38):

If you want to see only the date of a **tag** you'd do:

```
git show -s --format=%ci <mytagname>^{commit}
```

which gives: `2013-11-06 13:22:37 +0100`

Or do:

```
git show -s --format=%ct <mytagname>^{commit}
```

which gives UNIX timestamp: `1383740557`

Comment: This seems to give the date of the commit a tag points to, not the date of the tag its self.

Comment: @hoijui tags only have metadata (like date) if it's annotated

Comment: I tried to verify that, but now I get the same result for all tags I create, annotated or not, and it is neither the tagging date nor the commits date. I guess something is wrong on my side.

Answer (score 27):

If you like to have the timestamp without the timezone but local timezone do

```
git log -1 --format=%cd --date=local
```

Which gives this depending on your location

```
Mon Sep 28 12:07:37 2015
```

Comment: Is it possible to apply this for all the commits all in once?

Answer (score 10):

In case that you want to format the date (or hour) by yourself:

```
git show -s --date=format:'%Y%m%d-%H%M' --format=%cd  <commit id | default is the last commit>

# example output:
20210712-1948
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `git show` command.

To get the last commit date from git repository in a long(Unix epoch timestamp):

- **Command:** `git show -s --format=%ct`
- **Result:** `1605103148`

**Note:** You can visit the [git-show](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show) documentation to get a more detailed description of the options.

Answer (score 2):

if you got troubles with windows cmd command and .bat
just escape percents like that

```
git show -s --format=%%ct
```

> The % character has a special meaning for command line parameters and FOR parameters. 
>   To treat a percent as a regular character, double it: %%

[Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

Answer (score 1):

I know the question was asked a long time ago and I don't know which version of git this was.

For git version 2.37.3 the command

```
git show -s
```

will show the author date, not the commit date.
To get the commit date of a commit use

```
git log -1 --format=fuller 'commit hash'
```