# Caffe fully convolutional CNN

Tags: git, caffe

I am trying to finetune the fully convolutional CNN  for my problem. It seems I have an out-of-date Caffe installed in my machine.

It was mentioned in https://github.com/shelhamer/fcn.berkeleyvision.org that "These models are compatible with BVLC/caffe:master @ 8c66fa5 with the merge of PRs BVLC/caffe#3613 and BVLC/caffe#3570."

I am not familiar with the merges and PRs. What does this mean?
How can I install "BVLC/caffe:master @ 8c66fa5 with the merge of PRs BVLC/caffe#3613 and BVLC/caffe#3570"?

Comment: I suppose you can `git pull upstream master` to get latest version.

Answer (score 0):

`BVLC/caffe:master` indicates the branch `master` of the caffe repository. `8c66fa5` is the checksum of a specific commit. You can find out the date of a commit with [git show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814926/git-commit-date)

```
git show -s --format=%ci 8c66fa5
```

which in this case returns `2016-04-15 01:02:02 -0700`. You can checkout this specific commit with `git fetch && git checkout 8c66fa5`.

As written by Shai, `git pull upstream master` will retrieve the latest version, which includes the changes of `8c66fa5` (unless the changes have been reverted).