# Get git commit details without "git" command

Tags: php, git

First, I've seen and read [Git commit date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814926/git-commit-date).

How can I get the date of the current HEAD commit in git repo *without* execution any "git" command? Example: I'm execution commands from PHP and I cannot call `exec`, but I want to get current commit details.

I have access to .git folder of this repo, but it doesn't seem to be useful for commit details. I was only able to get:

- Current branch from `.git/HEAD`
- Current commit id (SHA) from `.git/refs/heads/<branch>`

But no commit message and no commit date. Is there any way to get it from the fileset?

Comment: How about using a PHP library to access the git repository? I'm sure libgit2 will have some PHP bindings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't.

Well, you *might* be able to, but there are too many complex issues.

Specifically, each Git *object* is stored in a database of all objects, indexed by hash-ID keys.  Some objects are *loose:* stored as separate files.  Such a file is zlib-deflated.  Any zlib-inflator can read this file and turn the compressed data into readable, useful data, and what you will see if you do this with a commit hash ID is the actual commit object content:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree 1fd4a47af4942cbdee0bdcb4375612ab521a4a51
parent 5571d085b3c9c2aa9470a10bcf2b8518d3e4ec99
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1531941857 -0700
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1531941857 -0700

Third batch for 2.19 cycle

Signed-off-by: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>
```

(Here I have used a Git command to do the job, which violates your rule.)  The dates are those two time stamps on the `author` and `committer` lines.  You can simply decode them however you like, though remember to use the time zone offset, `-0700` here, as well.  (The internal content is prefixed with a header, in this case `commit <size>\0`, as all Git objects have headers.)

But *loose* is not the only way objects get stored.  Once an object has been lying around loose for a while, Git will eventually *pack* the object into a *pack file*.  The format of pack files is quite complicated.  It *is* documented—see [the Git technical documentation file](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/technical/pack-format.txt)—but it's subject to change and not worth coding when `git cat-file -p` already does all the work for you.

So, just use a Git command.  This does mean you need Git installed, but you probably need that anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like this. ORS is the line separator just in case you have multiple rows in the file.

awk 'BEGIN { ORS=" " }; { print $1 }' ./.git/FETCH_HEAD

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).