# How do I find the date of a git commit using only plumbing commands?

Tags: git, scripting, git-plumbing

There is already a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3814926) asking how to find the date of a commit in Git. However, all the answers to that question make use of the `git show` or `git log` commands, which are both [porcelain commands](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39847781); the standard wisdom on porcelain commands seems to be that their [output format may change](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6978402) and that using them in scripts should therefore be avoided wherever possible.

Is there a way to obtain the timestamp of a git commit using only plumbing commands?

Comment: Is there any reason to require a plumbing command rather than simply enforce a format to a porcelain command? E.g. `git log --pretty=format:%aD | head -1` or `git show --format="format:%aD" --no-patch HEAD`.

Comment: @pepak Only that, as I understand it, there's no guarantee that those commands will continue to give identical output in future versions of git. For instance, git 2.7.4 gives me `Mon, 8 Oct 2018` for the date in the `%aD` format, but I don't know whether I can reasonably expect that some future version won't produce `Mon, 08 Oct 2018` for the same commit.

Comment: Well, since the `%aD` format is specified as "author date, RFC2822 style", the format should remain the same. To get another fixed format, you could use `%aI` or add a dedicated `--date=raw`. Neither of these should change with a larger probability than the "plumbing" version.

Comment: @pepak RFC2822 permits but doesn't require a leading zero, so ‘RFC2822 style’ doesn't guarantee either variant. I agree it seems unlikely that `%aI` will change, but since the git docs explicitly say that porcelain commands are subject to change and shouldn't be used in scripts (except of course in cases where they offer a `--porcelain` option), I would prefer not to rely on second-guessing their future development.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The format of a commit object is as follows:

```
tree SP SHA_1_NAME_AS_HEX LF
parent SP SHA_1_NAME_AS_HEX LF
...
author SP any number of words SP <email_addr> SP TIMESTAMP SP TZ_OFFSET LF
committer SP any number of words SP <email_addr> SP TIMESTAMP SP TZ_OFFSET LF
LF
commit message LF
LF
extensive commit message
```

(Where `SP` is an ASCII space character, 0x20, and `LF` is an ASCII line-feed character, 0x0a).

So basically to achieve what you want, you:

1. Call `git cat-file commit <commitish_of_interest>`
2. Iterate over what that program dumps to its `stdout`
   by `LF`-terminated lines.
3. Stop at the line which starts with `author SP`.
4. Split it on spaces, and take the last two fields.
   The first one is the number of seconds since `00:00` in the timezone defined by the second field, which has the format
   `SHHMM` where `S` is a sign, `-` or `+`, whcih defines where the offset if to the West of, or to the East of Greenwich, correspondingly, and `HHMM` is the offset, in `HH` hours and `MM` minutes, of the timezone.
5. Process the values of these two fields to format the timestamp.

Note that the contents of the `author` and `committer` fields are the same only on "normal" commits. On rebased commits at least timestamps may differ, and if a commit was rebased by a person other than who actually authored the commit (its author), the fields will be different. The same is also true for commits created from patches via `git am`.

Answer (score 2):

`git cat-file -p HASH_OF_COMMIT` will return the content of the commit blob.
So you will have access to all the Metadata and so, the author and creation dates.

Answer (score 1):

Git is a little lax on properly distinguishing between plumbing and porcelain.  The advice to use plumbing commands in scripts is good, but sometimes a command—such as `git log`—doesn't have an appropriate plumbing variant, but *does* have options that make it "plumby", if I can make up a word.

In this case, an appropriate command is (edited, 21 Mar 2019, per [comment from Josh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708548/how-do-i-find-the-date-of-a-git-commit-using-only-plumbing-commands/52709749?noredirect=1#comment97308019_52709749)):

```
git -c log.showSignature=false log --pretty=format:%ad --no-walk <hash>
```

(or the same with `%cd` as the format directive for committer date; add various date formatting options, to `git log` itself, or as `%aD` for instance, to change the date format).  Nothing exactly promises that `git log` might not add new features, such as the `log.decorate` setting, that might disrupt this, and Git should get with itself and add `--porcelain` options to the commands that behave like `git status` does.  (Note that `git status` now has `--porcelain` and `--porcelain=v2`, both of which convert it to plumbing.  Don't ask me why this isn't spelled `--plumbing`...)

Comment: Thanks. I've noticed the `--porcelain` option for `status` (and for the `--word-diff` option, but no others, of `show` and `log`), but of course this just makes me *more* wary of using porcelain commands that *don't* have a `--porcelain` option :). I suppose some things (e.g. `--pretty=format:%at`) are particularly unlikely to change, but it would be nice to have it in writing...

Comment: It would be easy for the Git folks to add now, too, since `git log --porcelain` could just imply *ignore log.decorate and ui.color settings* or something close to that... (oops, `ui.color` is Mercurial, `color.*` for Git. Too many VCSes...)

Comment: This is not resilient in the face of unusual user configuration! If the user has set `log.showSignature`, then this will also output several more lines from gpg, which tends to break whatever's expecting a single date.

Comment: @Josh: ugh. So `git -c log.showSignature=false log --pretty=...`, then.  This is why `git log` should have a plumbing equivalent.