# How do I get branch created timestamp with PHP?

Tags: php, git, git-shell

I want to get created Git branch (hotfix / feature) timestamp with [shell_exec](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php).

I tried below,

```
shell_exec("git show --summary `git merge-base your_branch master`");
```

But it showing `null`.

Does anyone know how to get it with php ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3814926/git-commit-date

Answer (score 0):

You used correct command for getting commit-hash (`git merge-base`), but `git show --summary`for branchpoint is **damned delirium**!!!

```
git show -s --format=%ci <...>
```

or [another formats](http://schacon.github.io/git/git-show) for another timestamp's representation